# sql query - variables - date - visual studio 210

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, date-comparison

Trying to search between two dates to only get certain `rows`. A 7 day search.

```
   @date = DateTime.Today
   @date2 = //need it to be the prior 7 days

SelectCommand = "SELECT [DateReceived], [DeviceLevel] FROM [TBLReadings] WHERE [DateReceived=@date] <= [DateReceived=@date2] ORDER BY [DateReceived] DESC;
```

This is wrong but I hope it explain what I am trying to do - only ever used `PHP` and `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to search between 2 dates, you can use `between`

the query will be something like

```
select [dateRecieved], [DeviceLevel] from YourTable where DateReceived between @date and @date2 ORDER BY [DateReceived] DESC
```

in c#, to get 7 days you can use `Datetime.Now.AddDays(7)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx

sorry for the bad english!

edit: that's only the query, use it as a string in the select command

Comment: the AddDays will put the days on surely, I want to take them away.

so I can search the past week for data.

Though using other forms of SQL I have been told to avoid the between function, maybe in this format it is fine

Comment: so add "negative" days. `Datetime.Now.AddDays(-7)`
If you are not sure of between usage, the where clause that you wrote will work too

Comment: about between clause, you can read from here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921282/compare-performance-difference-of-t-sql-between-and-operator
about performance, it's the same use between or "> and <"

Comment: That helped a bit. I do not know how to declare my variables to work in the SelectCommand.

Comment: you can use parameters in querys. Avoiding concatenate strings is easiear and will prevent sql injections. 
You can do something like
`SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = yourSelectCommand;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTime.Now.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", DateTime.Now.ToString());` and execute the query that I wrote up there.

Comment: read more: http://forums.asp.net/t/1359766.aspx/1 example about sql connection and use
format string (just in case) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx.
Edit: in @Date2 AddWithValue, it's `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString(). My mistake!`

Comment: Thanks @ELVieejo. Worked a treat.